# C# dll and Silverlight communication using TCP/IP

Tags: silverlight

Can I use TCP/IP for communication between a dll written in C# and a Silverlight 5 Application, both running on the same Windows 7 machine? Are there any security issues that I should be aware of?

Comment: Could you provide some more detail about the scenario and describe what you want to achieve by this construction?

Answer (score 0):

To start with the DLL must be a Silverlight DLL or it will not work. Silverlight cannot access dlls from non-silverlight projects.

If it is a Silverlight dll you can set a reference to it in your project and it will be distributed in the XAP file.

The TCP/IP part of this question is not really meaningful as that is a protocol you would use (explicitly) to call a WCF service, and is not relevant to the problem.

EDIT
Also, if the DLL has been compiled with COM interop enabled you can use late binding to call it.